# Como sumar dos input que ya tienen un valor preestablecido

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.cl').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#sumAll').val(add);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="tery7" id="c1" class="cl" onChange="suma();" value="100">
<br>
<input type="text" name="tery8" id="c2" class="cl" onChange="suma();" value="300">
<br>
<input id="sumAll" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuando se ejecute el codigo automaticamente se sumen los dos valores y se muestren en el tercer input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo te falta agregar el manejador de jQuery `$(document).ready()`

```js
$( document ).ready(suma);
function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.cl').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#sumAll').val(add);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="tery7" id="c1" class="cl" onChange="suma();" value="100">
<br>
<input type="text" name="tery8" id="c2" class="cl" onChange="suma();" value="300">
<br>
<input id="sumAll" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!